# How can I loop through an array, starting at an offset and looping round again?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Newb question: I'm using a foreach loop to get items from an array.

I need to start looping at an offset number- (I'm using a $i variable to do this, no problem).

But when my foreach reaches the end of the array I want it to start going through the array again until it reaches the offset number.

I need to do this so I can have a user open any image in an artist's portfolio and have this image used as the first image presented in a grid of thumbnail icons , with all the other images subsequently populating the rest of the grid.

Any ideas?
Please bear in mind I'm new to PHP! :)
See below for an example of my current code...

```
       $i=0;
        $limit=50;// install this in the if conditional with the offset in it (below) to limit the number of thumbnails added to the page.
        $offset=$any_arbitrary_link_dependant_integer;

        foreach($portfolio_image_array as $k=>$image_obj){//$k = an integer counter, $image_obj = one of the many stored imageObject arrays.
            $i++;
            if ($i > $offset && $i < $limit) {// ignore all portfolio_array items below the offset number.
                if ($img_obj->boolean_test_thing===true) {// OK as a way to test equivalency?
                    // do something
                } else if ($img_obj->boolean_test_thing===false) { // Now add all the non-see_more small thumbnails:
                    // do something else
                } else {
                    // error handler will go here.
                }
            } // end of offset conditional

        }// end of add boolean_test_thing thumbnails foreach loop.
    };// end of add thumbnails loop.
```

Comment: You can use a modulo division for this: use a numeric for loop instead of foreach, and reference the array entries not by the loop index variable, but by that modulo your offset.

Comment: then use `for loop`, which has customized start and end values

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to use two separate numeric for loops, the first going from offset to end, and the second going from beginning to offset.

```
<?php
// Create an example array - ignore this line
$example = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

$offset = 3;

// Standard loop stuff
$count = count($example);
for($i = $offset; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    echo $example[$i]."<br />";
}

for($i = 0; $i < $offset; $i++)
{
    echo $example[$i]."<br />";
}

?>
```

This is also almost certainly cheaper than doing multiple checks on every single element in the array, and it expresses exactly what you are trying to do to other programmers who look at this code - including yourself in 2 weeks time.

Edit: depending on the nature of the array, in order to use numeric keys you may first need to do `$example = array_values($portfolio_image_array);`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the speedy response Mark & Marcus! I'll give it a go when I'm back at my desk tonight and report back.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$limit = 50;
$offset = $any_arbitrary_link_dependant_integer;
$count = count($portfolio_image_array);
        foreach($portfolio_image_array as $k=>$image_obj){//$k = an integer counter, $image_obj = one of the many stored imageObject arrays.
        $i++;
        if ($i > $offset && $i < $limit && $i < ($count - $offset)) {// ignore all portfolio_array items below the offset number.
            if ($img_obj->boolean_test_thing===true) {// OK as a way to test equivalency?
                // do something
            } else if ($img_obj->boolean_test_thing===false) { // Now add all the non-see_more small thumbnails:
                // do something else
            } else {
                // error handler will go here.
            }
        } // end of offset conditional

    }// end of add boolean_test_thing thumbnails foreach loop.
};
```

Only thing I added was a $count variable.

*Edit: If your array starts at 0 I would suggest you put the `$i++;` at the end of your foreach loop.*

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the speedy response Mark & Marcus! I'll give it a go when I'm back at my desk tonight and report back.

Comment: No problem. I would like to hear from you which solution worked the best for you ;)

Comment: Hallo Mark, I've tried your solution but I think I should have also implemented one of the other solutions too? My array is looped through from the offset but does not start over again to loop back to the offset. My tester page is here, if that helps: http://www.runninghead.com/portfolio.php?image_to_display=28
I've a couple of icons set to use different offsets over on the home page, for testing. Should be apparent from the URL, hopefully.
Please overlook the quality of images- they're just placeholders from many years ago! :)

Comment: I suggest you use 2 seperate loops.

Comment: OK @Mark Walet et al, not sure how to post correctly on this forum yet but here goes. I got the issue sorted as follows:
Thankyou so much for all the help! 
:)

Answer (score 0):

Using Answer Question to force StackOverflow to let me post a decent length of text!
OK @Mark Walet et al, not sure how to post correctly on this forum yet but here goes. I got the issue sorted as follows:

```
$i=0;
$offset=$image_to_display_number;
    $array_length = count($portfolio_image_array);

    // FIRST HALF LOOP:
    foreach($portfolio_image_array as $k=>$img_obj){// go through array from offset (chosen image) to end.
    if ($i >= $offset && $i <= $array_length) {
            echo write_thumbnails_fun($type_of_thumbnail, $image_path, $k, $i, $portfolio_image_array, $title, $image_original);
            $t_total++;// update thumbnail total count.
        }
        $i++;
    }// end of foreach loop 1.
    $looped=true;// Just FYI.
    $i=0;// Reset.
    // SECOND HALF LOOP:
    foreach($portfolio_image_array as $k=>$img_obj){// go through array from beginning to offset.
        if ($i < $offset) {
            echo write_thumbnails_fun($type_of_thumbnail, $image_path, $k, $i, $portfolio_image_array, $title, $image_original);
        }
        $i++;
    }// end of foreach loop 2.
```

Thankyou so much for all the help! 
:)

Answer (score 0):

as [@arkascha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673312/how-can-i-loop-through-an-array-starting-at-an-offset-and-looping-round-again/61131749#comment32761192_21673312) suggested use modulo operator

```
<?php

$example = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$count = count($example);
$offset = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $idx = ($offset + $i) % count 
  echo $example[$idx]."<br />";
}
?>
```